# resolving jasper reports dependency in maven

Tags: maven, jasper-reports

Upon putting jasper reports dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in my pom.xml, I am getting following error:

```
Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read local copy of metadata: Can
not read metadata from 'C:\mavenrepo\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-
collections\maven-metadata-jaspersoft.xml': end tag name </td> must match start
tag name <span> from line 257 (position: END_TAG seen ...</span></span></td>...
@261:173)
  commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:null

  from the specified remote repositories:
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.c
om/maven/bundles/external),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.co
m/maven/bundles/release),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  Springframework milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone),
  jaspersoft (http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2),
  jboss-public-repository-group (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/group
s/public),
  spring-maven-snapshot (http://s3.amazonaws.com/maven.springframework.org/snaps
hot)

Path to dependency:
        1) org.mytrac:mytrac:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:3.5.0
```

According to post: http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=80434

I tried following solution:

In  **settings.xml** in **E:\maven home folder\apache-maven-2.2.1-bin\apache-maven-2.2.1\conf** folder:

I put :

```
<profile>
      <repositories>

        <repository>
                <id>jaspersoft</id>
                <name>Jasper Soft</name>
                <url>http://jasperforge.org/maven2/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
```

and mirror :

```
<mirror>
       <id>my-jasperreports-repository</id>
        <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <mirrorOf>jaspersoft</mirrorOf>
 </mirror>
```

But the problem still persists.

Any suggestions?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because you still have the corrupt file in your local repo, and Maven isn't updating it. Remove `C:\mavenrepo\.m2\repository\commons-collections\` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same problem
this is the output I get when I try to run a maven-install

> [INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.
>
> Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read local copy of
>   metadata: Cannot read metadata from
>   'C:\Users\jmr.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\maven-metadata-jaspersoft.xml':
>   entity reference name can not contain character =' (position:
>   START_TAG seen
>   ...www.sermonillustrationlibrary.org/blocked/nospiders?mod=8819&qlvc=...
>   @420:198)    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:null

how can I fix *maven-metadata-jaspersoft.xml*?

EDIT

fortunately, in the same directory there was other maven-metadata-??????.xml files and curiously all of them were the same
so I've just replaced the corrupted content of ....jaspersoft.xml with the same of any of the other files and if worked fine.